# Make default accessory type on UITableViewCellAccessoryType as a button

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to use the accessory type in Table View Cell not just an accessory, but also as a button.

```
tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailButton
```

For example I'm using detailButton for accessoryType which when I touch it, I could trigger an event (eg. pop up alert). I have tried make a custom button with and put it on table view cell as an accessory view, but I would like to know if using default accessory type is possible.
Is there anyway I could do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `accessoryType` with a type of `DetailButton` or `DetailDisclosureButton`, then you can implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method of `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`.

This method is called when the user taps on the accessory button.

If you want any sort of custom `UIButton` then you need to create the button and set it as the cell's `accessoryView`. Setup the `UIButton` like you would any button to respond to user taps.